# How to model normal distribution curve based on a few datapoints in Excel?

Tags: excel, regression, normal-distribution

I can't believe I'm not finding a simple answer on Google for this noob question.

I have a handful of datapoints (lets say 10) on scores and respective percentile ranks that are normally distributed, for example see below:

| Scores | Percentile rank |
| --- | --- |
| 846 | 96.5 |
| 809 | 91.0 |
| 729 | 67.8 |
| 592 | 27.7 |
| ... | ... |

I now want to use those datapoints to calculate the percentile ranks for scores for which I don't have datapoints. E.g. what would be the percentile rank for a score of 650?

I know how to do a linear regression in Excel, but for a normally distributed dataset this doesn't work obviously.

Comment: if you know the mean and standard deviation you can use the NORM.DIST, otherwise four random values are not enough to describe the curve and therefore you can't interpolate a given 5th value

Comment: I think you could try plotting the inverse probability function norm.s.inv(percentile/100) against the score but I agree you need more points.

Comment: Thanks very much. I do have a few more points, at least for some of the sets I’m working with. However I don’t have the mean or SD. Still possible?

Answer (score 0):

You have

[image]

where x is the value and p is the corresponding probability (percentile value/100).

so if you plotted NORM.S.INV(p) against x you would get a straight line with

[image]

and

[image]

so you could estimate

[image]

and

[image]

I simulated some data with a mean of 100 and SD of 10 - it works reasonably well, but that is with a fair number of points spread between -3 and +3 standard deviations, so it might not be very good on just a small number of points

[image]

The estimated mean is 99.5 and SD 9.75